# Upvote results in +3 reputation?

Tags: support

Not that it matters, but I was just wondering...

I just got +3 reputation for an upvote. But I always thought an upvote is +10, no?

[image]

Comment: Very strange! I thought I had an answer for you, but the more I look at it, the less I can explain this.

Comment: What did you had in mind? I did however offered a bounty of 50 reputation today... Maybe I reached my limit?

Comment: Hm, odd. Try looking at http://apple.stackexchange.com/reputation to get a second opinion.

Comment: Yes, then that would likely be the problem. There is a 200 reputation cap. If you offered the bounty after the +3, subsequent votes could still give you reputation, but the +10 would have passed the maximum.

Comment: Welcome to the big leagues. 1k and daily rep cap :-)

Comment: Hehe :-) Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, up votes on **answers** are worth +10 and up votes on **questions** are worth +5. There are exceptions. There is a daily reputation cap of 200, and if you hit it at the time you were upvoted, you would only receive the score that brings your total up to 200.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but take a look at my updated message... If I can count correctly, I count 219 reputation - 50 bounty = 169, right?

Comment: Right, but you don't have your results displayed chronologically. The cap applies at the time you hit it. If you got an upvote that would have brought you above 200 **before** you offered the bounty, your score would still be limited.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer :)